# Installing Apple Watch OS 2 App on Apple watch without iOS device

Tags: swift, apple-watch, xcode7, watchos-2

I have created a demo standalone app for Apple Watch OS 2 and It works fine in the simulator. I know the steps to install watch os 1 apps via your device but in my case I don't see Apple watch device in Xcode to run my app.

Below is the error I am seeing when I try to run it on the paired iPhone

https://www.dropbox.com/s/c4qx3gdbep15s61/Screenshot%202015-08-20%2013.19.33.png?dl=0

There are many tutorials on building apps for Watch OS 2 but I couldnt find any info on installing it directly on watch. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Though watch OS 2 apps can run independent of watch it still contains a phone part. You cannot build an ipa or something that you can take it to the watch and install. To confirm this you can create a new watch OS 2 app in your xcode and you can see the phone files also being created.

Answer (score 3):

You’ll build watch apps for watchOS 2 as extensions, just as you might build a share extension. These are dependent apps—the Apple Watch can’t install them without a paired iPhone.
That may sound weird but below are the three main parts of apple watch

- **iOS app**: This is the "host" application that runs on an iPhone or iPad. You can never run an app on the Apple Watch without a host app.
- **Watch app**: This is the bundle of files and resources that is included with the host app but then installed on the Apple Watch. The bundle includes the app’s storyboard and any images or localization files used in the storyboard.
- **Watch extension**: The last piece of the puzzle is the actual code that you write. This gets compiled and transferred to the Watch for execution. Any images or localizations accessed in code should be bundled with the extension.